# Round frames intersecting

Tags: ios, frame, geometry

Im trying to find out how to tell if my 2 round frames are intersecting each other. since they are round i cant use cgrectintersectsrect and am not sure how to go about this. is there a cgframeintersectsframe or something along those lines?

for my round uiimageviews i did

```
circle1 = [[uiimageview alloc] initwithframe:cgrectmake (100,100,50,50);
circle1.layer.cornerradius = 25;
circle1.clipstobounds = yes;
[self.view addsubview:circle1];
```

the other circle is basically like that too except with a different x and y origin
I also alreday imported quartzcore

Comment: If it's perfectly round and have the same size, the distance between the two centers is enough. It's easy maths behind (something like sqrt((center1.x-center2.x)*(center1.x-center2.x)+(center1.y-center2.y)*(center1.y-center2.y)). The distance has to be less than the 2*radius (50*2 in the case of circle1).

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the distance between the centers of your circles and check if it's smaller than the radius:

```
float distanceBetweenCenters = sqrt(pow(circle1.center.x - circle2.center.x, 2) + 
                                   pow(circle1.center.y - circle2.center.y, 2));
BOOL isIntersecting = distanceBetweenCenters <= 2 * radius;
```

This will tell you whether the circles are intersecting or touching each other. Replace the `<=` with `<` to exclude 'touching'.